# exsheets and the final grade table

Tags: tables

I am trying to build an exam using the excellent `exsheets` package. My problem is with the last table, the one that has the grades. Somehow, it seems that `\hline` does not provide a full table with line, existing a gap between the horizontal and vertical rules at each edge of table (see the image below).

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{exsheets}

\SetupExSheets{solution/print=true}

\newcommand*{\TBD}{\textcolor{red}{To be defined!}}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}{2}
\TBD
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
\TBD
\end{solution}

\begin{question}{1}
\TBD
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
\TBD
\end{solution}

\begin{question}{2}
\TBD
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
\TBD
\end{solution}

\begin{question}{3}
\TBD
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
\TBD
\end{solution}

\begin{question}{2}
\TBD
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
\TBD
\end{solution}

\begin{tabular}{|l|*{\numberofquestions}{c|}c|}
\hline
Question & \ForEachQuestion{\QuestionNumber{#1}\iflastquestion{}{&}} & Total \\
\hline
Points & \ForEachQuestion{\GetQuestionProperty{points}{#1}\iflastquestion{}{&}} & \pointssum* \\
\hline
P.\ student & \ForEachQuestion{\iflastquestion{}{&}} & \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the table and its lines have nothing to do with `exsheets` except that you use its macros to fill it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you mention has nothing to do with the `exsheets` class; it's well known that in standard LaTeX tables with vertical ahd horizontal rules have odd-looking corners because the horizontal rules end in the middle of the vertical ones:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
A & B \\
\hline
A & B \\
\hline
A & B \\
\hline
\end{tabular}    


\end{document}
```

produces (zoom at 400% (a bigger zoom would show the problem better, but 400% is the maximum I know how to obtain)):

[image]

Simply loading the `array` package fixes the problem:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
A & B \\
\hline
A & B \\
\hline
A & B \\
\hline
\end{tabular}    

\end{document}
```

Produces (zoom at 400%):

[image]

The problem mentioned can be illustrated more clearly using a large value for `\arrayrulewidth`; compare the odd result without `array`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

\setlength\arrayrulewidth{7pt}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
A & B \\
\hline
A & B \\
\hline
A & B \\
\hline
\end{tabular}    

\end{document}
```

[image]

versus using `array`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\setlength\arrayrulewidth{7pt}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
A & B \\
\hline
A & B \\
\hline
A & B \\
\hline
\end{tabular}    

\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way (I'm sure you know I was going to suggest this) your table would look better without vertical rules and using the featured provided by the [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\SetupExSheets{solution/print=true}

\newcommand*{\TBD}{\textcolor{red}{To be defined!}}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}{2}
\TBD
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
\TBD
\end{solution}

\begin{question}{1}
\TBD
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
\TBD
\end{solution}

\begin{question}{2}
\TBD
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
\TBD
\end{solution}

\begin{question}{3}
\TBD
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
\TBD
\end{solution}

\begin{question}{2}
\TBD
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
\TBD
\end{solution}

\begin{tabular}{@{}l *{\numberofquestions}{c} c@{}}
\toprule
Question & \ForEachQuestion{\QuestionNumber{#1}\iflastquestion{}{&}} & Total \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-6}\cmidrule(l){7-7}
Points & \ForEachQuestion{\GetQuestionProperty{points}{#1}\iflastquestion{}{&}} & \pointssum* \\
P.\ student & \ForEachQuestion{\iflastquestion{}{&}} & \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Gonzalo thanks! I was not aware of the problem with the lines in `tabular`, and mostly that `array` solves it. By the way, `booktabs` is superb! I didn't use it in my question because I was just trying to reproduce the example in `exsheets` and I found that problem.